# How do I find the Rockafellar-Fenchel dual derivation of reguarlized objective function?

Tags: convex-optimization, duality

I'm stuck finding the dual of this optimization problem:
$$ \max_{\tilde{u},\tilde{v}} \int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|x\right\|^2 + \tilde{u}(x)\right) \, ds(x) + \int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|y\right\|^2 + \tilde{v}(y)\right) \, dt(y) - \lambda (\left\| \tilde{u} \right\|_H^2 + \left\| \tilde{v} \right\|_H^2),\, \tilde{u}(x)+\tilde{v}(y)\leq -\langle x,y\rangle. $$

Let $E = C(X\times Y)$ be the set of continuous functions with sup. norm.
$E^{*} = M(X\times Y)$ is that of regular Radon measures with TV norm. $H$ is the RKHS (reproducing kernel hilbert space) that $\tilde{u}, \tilde{v}$ belong to.

$$g(z) = \begin{cases}
0, \, z(x,y) \geq -\langle x,y \rangle \\
+\infty, \, \textrm{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

$$f(z) = \begin{cases}
\int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|x\right\|^2 + \tilde{u}(x)\right) \, ds(x) + \int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|y\right\|^2 + \tilde{v}(y)\right) \, dt(y) - \lambda (\left\| \tilde{u} \right\|_H^2 + \left\| \tilde{v} \right\|_H^2), \, z(x,y)=\tilde{u}(x)+\tilde{v}(y) \\
+\infty, \, \textrm{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

$$\inf_{z\in E} [f(z)+g(z)] = -\sup_{(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})\in \Phi_c} \int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|x\right\|^2 + \tilde{u}(x)\right) \, ds(x) + \int \left( \frac{1}{2}\left\|y\right\|^2 + \tilde{v}(y)\right) \, dt(y) - \lambda (\left\| \tilde{u} \right\|_H^2 + \left\| \tilde{v} \right\|_H^2)$$

\begin{align*}
g^{*}(-\pi) &= \sup_{z\in E} \left[ -\int_{X\times Y} z\,d\pi - g(z)\right] \\
&= \sup_{z\in E} \left[ - \int_{X\times Y} z\,d\pi :\, -z(x,y)\leq \langle x,y\rangle  \right] \\
&= \begin{cases}
\int_{X\times Y} \langle{x,y\rangle}\,d\pi,\, \pi\in M_{+}(X,Y) \\
+\infty, \, \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f^{*}(\pi) &= \sup_{z\in E} \left[ -\int_{X\times Y} z\,d\pi - f(z)\right] \\
&= \begin{cases}
 \int -\frac{1}{2} \left\|x\right\|^2\,ds(x) - \frac{1}{2} \left\|y\right\|^2\,dt(y) + \lambda(\left\| \tilde{u} \right\|_H^2 + \left\| \tilde{v} \right\|_H^2), \, \pi\in \Pi(s,t) \\
 +\infty, \, \textrm{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

The dual problem is $\sup_{\pi\in E^{*}} \left[ -f^{*}(\pi)-g^{*}(-\pi)\right] $, which, from the above, is
$$\sup_{\pi\in \Pi(s,t)} \int \frac{1}{2} \left\|x\right\|^2\,ds(x) + \frac{1}{2} \left\|y\right\|^2\,dt(y) - \lambda(\left\| \tilde{u} \right\|_H^2 + \left\| \tilde{v} \right\|_H^2) - \int_{X\times Y} \langle x,y\rangle \,d\pi $$

I don't think my solution is correct because it still involves a sum of norms of $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{v}$. Anyone have any pointers?